# Google private apps close testing out side organization

Tags: android, google-play

I am publishing one private app which will be visible to a specific organization. I added their organization ID as per https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139?hl=en#zippy=%2Callow-rd-party-developer-publishing.

I published it on the close testing channel and added some of the tester's Gmail account but somehow that tester cannot find the app. The testers are not part of that organization. Can I add a third-party tester in the closed testing channel for the private apps? I can see that the application close testing is live on the console.

Each time it gave me an error.
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a tech support question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 1):

The console is not very descriptive here but when you add an organisation under managed google play it imposes the restriction to your closed testing track. Unless the testers are part of the organisation then they wont be able to access the app. We initially expected this not to be the case given the closed testing track had its own organisation settings but following testing we realised the issue.

In our case we had an app distributed to an organisation via manage play with organisation  id. The organisation however also wanted the app to be available to their external contractors but not publicly available on the play store. Closed testing was out first attempt at a work around but failed due to the above. We finally settled on creating a google group and posting a GDrive link to the APK. Whilst the link can be shared with anyone, only those within the group are able to download the APK. Unfortunately this means sideloading but without any properly support Google Play option (like vouchers on Apple App Store) we had no alternative.

Comment: I have a scenraio like i have. an existing app in production the version is 1.0 , i want to release version 1.1 as closed testing through google managed plays console there i can add org - id but when i ma adding and trying to publish its saying once i publish a s prive i can't make it public , What does it mean is it means that my existing 1.0 version will be private too?